# Toric Varieties Exercise 1.1.1

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

I've began working through some of Toric Varieties by Cox, Little, and Schneck, and need some basic help with this inclusion in problem 1.1.1.

Let $I = \langle x_ix_{j+1} - x_{i+1}x_j | 0 \leq i < j \leq d \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x_0,...,x_d]$

and let $\hat{C}_d$ be the surface paramaterized by

$$\phi(s,t) = (s^d,s^{d-1}t,...,st^{d-1},t^d) \in \mathbb{C}^{d+1}.$$

I just need to show that $V(I) = \phi(\mathbb{C}^2) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^{d+1}$.

Clearly $I = \langle x_0x_2 + x_1^2 \rangle$ and $\phi(\mathbb{C}^2) = (s^2,st,t^2)$, which makes the $\phi(\mathbb{C}^2) \subseteq V(I)$ inclusion very easy as
$$s^2t^2 -(st)^2 \implies s^2t^2 - s^2t^2 = 0.$$
The reverse inclusion eludes me somewhat embarrassingly. I know I can show this very easily using Grobner Bases and the Elimination/Extension Theorem but I would prefer a method that does not rely on computer algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observation is that, the generators of $I$ are related to the following matrix
$$A(x)=\begin{pmatrix} x_0&x_1&\cdots&x_{d-2}&x_{d-1}\\x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_{d-1}&x_d\end{pmatrix}.$$
In fact, the shown generators of $I$ are exactly the maximal minors by $i$-th and $j$-th columns of $A$, so we have the following interpretation.
$$x=(x_0,\dots,x_d)\in V(I) \Longleftrightarrow \text{all max. minors of $A(x)$ vanish} \Longleftrightarrow \mathrm{rank }\ A(x)\leq 1.$$

Now, to see $V(I)\subset\phi(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is not difficult: if $x\in V(I)$ then $\mathrm{rank }\ A(x)\leq 1$ and so we have for some $(q,p)\neq (0,0)$,
$$qA(x)^{(1)}-pA(x)^{(2)}=0, \text{ i.e., }qx_i=px_{i+1}\ (0\leq i\leq d-1)$$
where $A(x)^{(i)}$ denotes the $i$-th row of $A(x)\ (i=1,2)$.
When $p=0$, we have $A(x)^{(1)}=0$ and
$x$ is the image of $(0,\sqrt[d]{x_d})\in\mathbb{C}^2$. When $p\neq 0$, we have from the equations $$x=(x_0,(q/p)x_0,\dots,(q/p)^dx_0),$$
so letting $s=\sqrt[d]{x_0}$ and $t=sq/p$ gives the desired form
$$x=(s^d,ts^{d-1},\dots,t^d).$$
The other inclusion will be more obvious.

Notes: This map $\phi$ is a form of famous one, called the *Veronese embedding* of $\mathbb{P}^1$. The observation above is based on that its image is a *determinantal variety*.

Comment: Please use markdown to format text, i.e. `*italics*` for *italics*, instead of \textit. I've made the change for you this time.

Comment: Ah good, this is exactly what I was looking for. I know I can also show this using Grobner Basis Calculations and Elimination Theory but I was looking for a more instructive approach rather than relying on computer algebra.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, @KReiser. I never knew it.

Comment: I'm happy to be of your help. @CookieBouquets